# Is it possible to display code line by line with slidify?

Tags: r, animation, r-markdown, slidify

For teaching purpose, I would like to make some R code appear line by line for an interactive course with students. I found the interactive console of [slidify (ou have to run the video to see what it means at 4'55)](http://slidify.github.io/dcmeetup/demos/interactive/), but I would like to know if it is possible to hide/show the code or better, to show the code line by line (an option or an animation?).

I add the code I found as demo of the interactive console below but the fact that the code appears in an interactive console is not a high requirement for me, I just want to evaluate the code after having displayed it entirely (preferably without writing multiple slides for one exercise).

````
--- &interactive
## Interactive Console

``{r opts.label = 'interactive', results = 'asis'}
require(googleVis)
M1 <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar = 'Fruit', timevar = 'Year')
print(M1, tag = 'chart')
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Near the end of this tutorial, there is a great explanation of how to sequentially reveal R code and he has posted the code as well.

http://zevross.com/blog/2014/11/19/creating-elegant-html-presentations-that-feature-r-code/